# How to get the current namespace of current context using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to get the namespace of the currently used Kubernetes context using `kubectl`.

I know there is a command `kubectl config get-contexts` but I see that it cannot output in json/yaml. The only script I've come with is this:

```sh
kubectl config get-contexts --no-headers | grep '*' | grep -Eo '\S+$'
```

Comment: looking at all the answers, i'm honestly shocked that there isn't a simple command for showing current ns in k8s..

Answer (score 167, accepted):

This works if you have a namespace selected in your context:

```
kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{..namespace}'
```

Also, [kube-ps1](https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1) can be used to display your current context and namespace in your shell prompt.

Comment: Straight to the point. Consider adding the recommendation of [kube-ps1](https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1)  to your answer.

Comment: for me this only worked when `--minify` parameter was omitted: `kubectl config view --output 'jsonpath={..namespace}'`

Comment: `--minify` removes all output not used by the current context from the output.  Therefore it's required to correctly print the current default namespace.  If it doesn't print anything, you probably don't have a current-context set with a namespace.  Verify using `kubectl config current-context`

Comment: Just for information, if you are already in default namespace; it is possible that you might not getting anything as a response of this command.

Comment: If running from the command line adding `; echo` at the end makes for a slightly more readable response: `kubectl config view --minify --output 'jsonpath={..namespace}'; echo`

Answer (score 31):

```
kubectl config view | grep namespace
```

Comment: this just greps all namespaces from your configuration and does not only show the one currently used. You are missing the "--minify" argument: "Remove all information not used by current-context from the output"

Comment: to cut from grep response: `kubectl config view | grep namespace: | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d" " -f2`

Comment: Just for information, if you are already in default namespace; it is possible that you might not getting anything as a response of this command.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow please don't edit to change answers into meaningfully different answers.  An answer with `--minify` [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64242488/208273(); there was no need for another one.

Answer (score 24):

Print the current namespace being used:

```
kubectl config view --minify | grep namespace
```

Comment: This does not work for me - it lists multiple namespaces, and also lists namespaces in other contexts!

Comment: This would grep out just the namespace value: `kubectl config view --minify | grep -Po 'namespace: \K.*'`

Answer (score 19):

Use the default service account:

```
kubectl describe sa default | grep Namespace
```

Answer (score 16):

**1. Using service accounts of the current namespace**

At least one service account exists in current namespace, so use it to retrieve the current namespace:

```sh
NS=$(kubectl get sa -o=jsonpath='{.items[0]..metadata.namespace}')
```

**2. kubectl**

Sometimes `kubectl config view --minify` will not display `default` namespace, so a more robust solution to get the namespace is:

```sh
NS=$(kubectl config view --minify --output 'jsonpath={..namespace}')
NS=$([ ! -z "$NS" ] && echo "$NS" || echo "default")
```

**3. kubens plugin**

kubens plugin, https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/blob/master/kubens, is also an interesting solution:

```sh
# kubens -c
default
```

Comment: I like `kubens` -- good callout on it's ability to show currently selected ns.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. No one speaks about why `default` namespace isn't being picked up by `--minify` but this one is really helpful & kudos to kubens.

Answer (score 3):

The jsonpath={..namespace} didn't worked for me and as I have more than one context I ended up with :

```
kubectl config view --output 'jsonpath={.contexts[?(@.name=="'$(kubectl config current-context)'")].context.namespace}';echo
```

Comment: Wonderful answer!

Answer (score 3):

This will output exact namespace name:

```bash
$ kubectl get sa default -o=jsonpath='{.metadata.namespace}'
```

It extract it from the default Service Account using jsonpath query.

Couple of assumptions for this to work correctly:

1. You did not change name of the `default` Service Account, which is `default` by default and it exists in every K8s namespace.
2. Network connection to the cluster is working.

Otherwise, you can only get the namespace from the `kubeconfig` file, using other methods provided here.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the namespace of the current context by making use of the commands `kubectl config current-context` and `kubectl config view` as follows:

```
kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.contexts[?(@.name == '$(kubectl config current-context)')].context.namespace}"
```

However I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854690/5655567 is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl config view --minify --flatten
```

This gives you everything related to your current context.
You can get the following:

- Namespace
- Cluster name
- User
- Cluster certificate
- User token

Answer (score 1):

In `kubectl` drop-in replacement provided by Red Hat for their `k8s`-compatible platforms (Openshift and OKD) called `oc Client Tools` (which you can connect to any standard micro[k8s] cluster API server) finding out the current namespace is much simpler*:

```
oc project
```

Sample output:

```
Using project "ml" on server "https://localhost:8080".
```

---

*(note that `project` is a synonym of Kubernetes  `namespace`/`ns`, but they cannot be used fully interchangeably, so `oc ns` would not work, while `oc get ns` will list *all* namespaces in a k8s cluster, and would not work in an OCP/OKD cluster).

Answer (score 0):

```
# short alias to set/show context/namespace (only works for bash and bash-compatible shells, current context to be set before using kn to set namespace) 
alias kx='f() { [ "$1" ] && kubectl config use-context $1 || kubectl config current-context ; } ; f'
alias kn='f() { [ "$1" ] && kubectl config set-context --current --namespace $1 || kubectl config view --minify | grep namespace | cut -d" " -f6 ; } ; f'
```

For more kubectl code check this usefull cheatsheet:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

Comment: Can anyone explain the reason for the aliases? I presume they are just cargo cult programming, see https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/32275#issuecomment-1068025961 . Why not plain functions kx and kn?

Comment: Personal opinion:
Aliases makes your life easier, fast to write, less errors and you don't have to remember long lines by heart.
You can also make functions and combine multiple commands

Comment: But functions do all those things, too. And they are already used here. So, what's the advantage of `alias kx='f() { … }; f'` over the simpler plain function `kx() { … }`?

Comment: If you have an alias you can reuse it from any terminal, you will write only 2 letters: kx
Define once use everytime

Comment: If you have a function called kx, you can call it exactly like that.

Comment: I got your point. But if you have, alias k= kubectl.
You can do: k get ns, for example.
which cannot be done by functions..
Alias is like variables that can be reused but function are like actual functions; using programming terms

Comment: To support that, the function just needs to handle args (which kx and kn already do to some extend, `$1`). They need to pass the arg at a specific point in the pipe, so an alias won't work, so they use functions. (I'd also use a function, but without a wrapper alias.) Re your k alias: Doesn't this function behave the same? `k() { kubectl "$@"; }; k get ns`. For this, I'd use an alias, too, because it's shorter and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you stay in json speaK:

```
kubectl config view --minify -ojson |jq '.contexts[0].context.namespace'
```